# Cannot run Parallels Transporter Agent due to disk errors

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk, parallels

I'm trying to clone my old Windows 7 machine to a Parallels VM image, but the Parallels Transporter Agent refuses to work because of disk errors.

[image: This PC could not be transferred. A hard disk check found errors that prevented transferring the PC. To attempt to fix the problem, open the command-line interface as an administrator and run the "chkdsk /F" command. Your computer will restart. After that, open Parallels Transporter Agent and try the transfer again.]

I've run `chkdsk c: /R /F` multiple times, but every time I get a bunch of messages like this:

```
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 209618.
```

That sounds like `chkdsk` is fixing the errors, but every time I run it the same messages show up, and the migration assistant still refuses to run.

Even though these errors are present, they've never interfered with my use of the computer.

How can fix these errors, or get the Transporter Agent to accept the disk?

Comment: Sounds like the hard drive is failing, hope you data is backup already.

Comment: CHKDSK will work unless the records are physically damaged. So it may have been spot damage and the records replaced with the original damaged records isolated, or as suggested, the disk is failing. If the former and CHKDSK cannot correct, you may not be able to correct the cloning

Comment: It actually seems like something that runs at boot is corrupting the drive.  I finally made a recovery CD to run chkdsk.  I can run it there multiple times and the errors don't show up after the first run.  However, they'll show up again when I run chkdsk after booting Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working after struggling with it for some time.  It appears that something installed in my OS was causing the filesystem corruption.  I learned that by making a Windows recovery disk, then running `chkdsk /f` several times in a row.  It would only see errors after the first run.  Rebooting and trying again would cause the disk errors to return.

I suspected Trend Micro Office Scan, uninstalled it in Safe Mode.  Then I ran another `chkdsk /f` from a Windows recovery disk.  I tried running a `sfc /scannow` from the disk for good measure, but it wouldn't allow me since it wanted to make other repairs (I think this was because I used the power button to try to interrupt the boot to insert the recovery CD).

I rebooted again, ran `sfc /scannow` in non-safe-mode (it found no errors).  I then tried the Transporter Agent again, not thinking it would work.  However, it worked!

I think the root issue was Trend Micro.  It's always been trouble.